How to control python onvif camera ptz?
from onvif import ONVIFCamera
mycam = ONVIFCamera("192.168.0.60", 80, "admin", "password")
media = mycam.create_media_service()

If you run it as above, the following error will occur
onvif.exceptions.ONVIFError: Unknown error: Device doesn`t support service: media

The camera I use is a camera I bought from AliExpress. The camera is recognized in onvif device manager and I also confirmed rtsp playback in vlc media.
The cameras I purchased are as follows:
https://aliexpress.com/item/1005006124663195.html
Is the error occurring because the camera does not support onvif? The purchase page says that onvif is supported. Or is there something wrong with the source?

Use the ONVIF Device Manager to verify which ONVIF services are available on the camera. Check if the "Media" service is listed.

Are you using on phone or PC?
